# How do I remove old concrete from these flagstones?

Tags: concrete

I am building a walkway with red sandstone flagstones and would like to remove some old concrete that has adhered to some of them
[image: as shown here]

Is there a method to remove this thin layer of concrete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, resurfacing concrete this is a fun one. First, you have to pressure wash the surface to remove any loose bits. From there it depends on what you want to do here is a video on resurfacing.
https://youtu.be/lkl3bY7Z88k
other than that I would use a high grit sander to get those little loose bits off I mean it is unconventional but should work here is a link to what I would use https://www.empireabrasives.com/4.5-resin-fiber-sanding-grinding-disc-25-pack/?gclid=CjwKCAjw75HWBRAwEiwAdzefxOO_ySB5yXnu4JhcLT_SfQrGoFzGM87xfQ70k2C_J4voi_iRdTz07xoCptYQAvD_BwE
Be sure to post an after pic so we can see how it turns out

Comment: The video seems to be about concrete resurfacing. I wish to remove the thin layers of concrete from the surface of sandstone. Would an acid treatment work?

Comment: That might be a little more work than I would be willing to put in when concrete usually gets like this it is best to resurface or sand it